# Photos of people in airplanes specifically not permitted

Tags: air-travel, privacy

I took a few flights recently, and for the first time ever (for me), all passengers were told before departing that "taking photos or videos of other passengers or crew is not permitted unless you get permission from them". Seems like this is really being enforced, because on one flight an elderly passenger who took a photo of his partner also got other people in the frame and a crew member sat down with him to get him to delete the photo.

One flight was from South America to Spain with Air Europa; the other one a flight within Europe with Transavia. This is the first time in many years that I have encountered this.

Is this something new? Where is this coming from? New legislation?

Comment: Recent-ish legislation in some countries means consent is needed for just taking a photograph of one or more identifiable people, even in a public place, and it is becoming increasingly common for consent to be required before publishing it (which would include on social media) even if such publication is not for commercial purposes https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Country_specific_consent_requirements

Comment: @Traveller that would mean that pretty much any photos in public places are just impossible?

Comment: Asking the elderly passenger to delete the photo seems like a weird first move (if it was indeed the first move). Shouldn't the first move be to give the option to ask permission from the passengers in the picture, or to delete and retake with no unapproved passenger in the picture?

Comment: In many countries, *publishing* photos with someone without their consent has been forbidden for decades. *Taking* the photos was allowed, though, but of course to enforce the former it’s a lot easier to forbid the latter.

Comment: I'm not aware of any new legislation, but taking/publishing photos of strangers hasn't been all that acceptable or legal in many places for quite a few years/decades now. Maybe this was in response to one country changing their laws (which encouraged/forced airlines to follow suit), maybe it was in response to a recent incident or maybe they did it unprompted.

Comment: Another data point: I travelled with Vueling between Spain and Belgium this month and there wasn't any such announcement on either of the two flights.

Comment: There is absolutely no problem taking photos of people in public spaces in the UK, and publishing them. I can take any picture I want with any strangers in it and post it online on social media. It is only an issue in commercial usage - consent is required then. Some exceptions apply, eh military bases, some parts of airports, etc

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apart from the legal aspect, I could imagine another reason why new policies concerning filming (and photographing) on board have been established: 
There seems to be an increase in video footage of passengers and airline personnel in controversial situations (e.g. concerning enforcement of health-related mask mandates) going viral online in the last years. Maybe airlines want an easy way to at least control production of such footage.

Comment: Also, a photo of a passenger could be linked to a certain flight, creating proof of someone's presence or absence in some place at some time. That is exactly the kind of information considered sensitive personal data.

Comment: Thanks. I'll mark this as accepted as it most directly explains where this might be coming from. Appreciate all the answers.

Comment: Definitely airlines must be alert to things going viral. There are various reasons around image-capturing that may apply: COVID/mask-related harassment adds to existing problems like Islamophobia; people filming cabin crew (and the cabin crew objecting); harassment of other passengers, like men making creepy images of woman passengers or crew (upskirts, sleeping, down-blouse shots, etc); people filming passengers behaving badly, which is likely to cause arguments and fights; anything that give a negative impression of the airline. It's definitely easier to just ban entirely.

Comment: Also the possibility of people deliberately doing stuff to create confrontation or memorable moments, and filming it to create social media content. A lot of anti-mask people have tried to provoke by removing or not wearing masks and filming it. But there's a huge range of stunts on TikTok and other social media that involve filming people without their permission.

Answer (score 16):

> Photos of people in airplanes specifically not permitted. [...] Where is this coming from?

Typically, from the airline policy, as it's the case [in the US where airplanes are not considered public spaces](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/rules-of-taking-photos-and-videos-on-planes/):

> Airlines have more power on planes because as private parties they are not bound by the First Amendment. "They are within their rights to establish these rules, they are within their rights to throw you off the aircraft if you continue filming," says Joseph Larsen, a media-law attorney in Houston.

Note that unlike planes, airports are considered public spaces in the US:

> Lawyers who specialize in First Amendment or travel law say airlines generally cannot limit photography or video recording in an airport because it is a public space.

As [Traveller](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/60926/traveller) [mentioned](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179457/photos-of-people-in-airplanes-specifically-not-permitted#comment453971_179457), countries are increasingly [restrictive](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Country_specific_consent_requirements) about taking pictures in public spaces.

Comment: then again, photography in airports is often restricted not under privacy law but for security reasons, a fantastic blanket excuse

Comment: I am not sure "they are within their rights to throw you off the aircraft if you continue filming" is correct while the aircraft is in the air.  They would at least need to land before throwing you off

Comment: @Henry post DJ Cooper, they lack the capability as aircraft doors can no longer be opened in flight. Outside of national airspace especially, I'm not too sure about them not having the right :)

Comment: @jwenting [DB Cooper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D._B._Cooper).  (DJ Cooper is a basketball player)

Comment: @jwenting You're not allowed to commit murder in international waters. I can't imagine it would be allowed on airplanes either. Figuring out which jurisdiction to prosecute in might be a problem, but there will always be somebody.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just wonder why multiple airlines are suddenly making these announcements. If no one noticed any recent change maybe it was just coincidence.

Comment: @AndrewRay /sarc "But, your honor, he was alive and healthy when he stepped out the door"

Comment: @AndrewRay IANAL (not a lawyer) but different countries can have jurisdiction at the same time: 1) the country in which the airplane is registered 2) the murderer's country of citizenship 3) the victim(s)'s country of citizenship 4) the country where the plane next lands.

Comment: Maybe even 5) the country where the airplane departed

Comment: @moonman239 Sure, my point was that at least one of 1-5 will have jurisdiction. You're never going to end up in a situation where somebody could not be prosecuted.

Comment: On Phillippine Airlines flight 434, a terrorist planted a bomb on a plane headed from Manila to the southern Phillippines and then onward to Japan. The bomb detonated on the Japanese leg while the plane was close to Japan, so the plane diverted to Okinawa and the Okinawa police investigated the situation. Since the terrorist only flew the first leg of the flight and went back to the Phillippines, the Filipino police started looking for the guy to arrest him.

Comment: Since he was also involved in the WTC bombing the previous year (1993) the US actually found a way to punish him for everything he did. He now sits in solitary confinement in a supermax prison in Colorado.

Comment: @AndrewRay "You're not allowed to commit murder in international waters" - is there anywhere where you _are_ allowed to commit murder?

Comment: @AaronF Depends on what you mean by "allowed." There are parts of Yellowstone park where you could hypothetically get away with anything. Is it illegal? Yes, but you couldn't be tried because it would be impossible for a constitutionally permissible jury to be empaneled.

Comment: How could airports be considered public spaces when e.g. "LAX is closed to the general public 24 hours a day, 7 days a week"? (see https://www.flylax.com/travelsafely#two section "LAX Hours of Operation and Access")

Comment: @spacetyper that page has a good deal of outdated information on it.  I wouldn't be certain that this restriction is currently in place.  But even if it is, an airport is a "public accommodation" -- as is an airplane.  A space isn't necessarily public or private for every purpose.  Like a restaurant, an airport and a vehicle operated by a common carrier are under the control of a private entity, yet that control is limited.

Answer (score 3):

Surely it depends on the jurisdiction to which the plane is subject, just like with ships? The law of the country under whose flag the plane flies applies to everyone in the plane, just as it would on land. If that country specifies restrictions on photographing people you are bound by those. Airlines may presumably apply their own rules within that framework. You have no a priori rights on the basis of where you come from.

I am not a lawyer.

Comment: To underline your point, Germany recognizes the right to one's own likeness, which limits your rights to take pictures of me and publish them.